# Submodule folders visible in past commitments

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I am testing git for the first time to check whether it can be a solution for my version control problem. I started playing with submodules and I noticed an unexpected behaviour.

Useful information:

- I am running git on OS
- My remote repository is on Bitbucket
- I work with terminal and check things with Sourcetree

This is the tree from Sourcetree:

[image]

The submodule "library" was added in the fourth commitment "I have a library now".

When I `git checkout master`, I see my repository correctly, with my ProjectFile.txt and my submodule "library":

[image]

I would expect to find only a readme file if I `git checkout <hash 1st commitment>`, but this is not the case. The .gitmodules disappears but the "library" folder with its content is still there:

[image]

If I go to my remote repository on Bitbucket and I checkout the same 1st commitment then I find no library folder as expected:

[image]

Why is the "library" folder popping up before it was actually added on my computer?

Notice that the "library" folder could not be there by mistake as the first commitment is present by default when a new repository on Bitbucket is created.

Comment: When you check out an older commit, Git no longer *needs* the submodule directory, but does not remove it from your work-tree. (This is to some extent a leftover historical bug - removing the submodule would destroy the submodule repository in the old days, so Git didn't. Now, it doesn't destroy the repository, but people expect the leave-it-there behavior, so Git can't remove it.) Apparently whatever work-tree browser you are using decides to show it, too.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. If you add your answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if you clone a repository and its submodules, but then check out a commit in which the submodules are not used, Git would remove the submodule directory.  However, there is a history-of-Git issue with doing this.

In the following discussion, remember that a submodule *is* a Git repository in its own right.  It is merely a Git repository whose current *commit* is being controlled by another Git, which we call the *superproject*.  The superproject Git has a list of submodules to use, and for each submodule, the commit within that submodule to check out / switch-to within that submodule.  Remember also that a Git repository is, at its heart, a pair of databases.  One database, usually the much larger one, holds all the internal Git objects: commits and their files and other supporting internal objects that make up the history.  The other database holds names, such as branch and tag names, and their mappings to commits.  There is a large layer of software atop these two databases to do source code management, but the databases themselves are essential to the process: nothing can go anywhere unless the commits exist and can be found.

Hence, a *repository* is this data collection, stored in a `.git` directory.  A *bare* repository is one that consists of just the `.git` directory: this is what one generally finds on servers and hosting sites like GitHub or Bitbucket.  A developer's repository consists of both the `.git` directory and a *work-tree* or *working tree*, where Git can extract the files from some commit so that you can work on them, and where you can work on those files and thus make new commits.

Note that the `.git` directory for the top level (superproject) repository is normally found *in the work-tree for that repository*.  That is, at the top of your work-tree, there is a hidden `.git` directory that contains the repository.

In modern Git—"modern" being defined here as Git version 2 and later, although some of this was also found in late 1.x versions—the normal storage layout for a repository and its submodules (if any) normally stores all of the submodule repositories within the `.git` directory that stores the superproject.  The mechanism for this is called *absorption:* the parent superproject "absorbs" the submodule's repository.  Hence, if the parent repository is in `path/to/repo/.git`, and the submodule's work-tree is in `path/to/repo/subm/`, the actual *repository* for `path/to/repo/subm/` is not `path/to/repo/subm/.git/` but rather `path/to/repo/.git/modules/subm/`.  You *will* find that there is a *plain file* named `path/to/repo/subm/.git`; this plain file contains the repository-path information that Git needs when operating within the submodule.

However, in very old versions of Git, some of which are still in use, this is *not* the case: the submodule's repository is actually stored in `path/to/repo/subm/.git`.  Moreover, if you create a *new* superproject and submodule pair, you might do this by running:

```
mkdir path/to/repo
cd path/to/repo

# now get into path/to/repo/subm and create the submodule first
mkdir subm; cd subm; git init
echo "submodule for whatever" > README.txt
git add README.txt
git commit -m initial
git push -u ...           # create submodule on the hosting system

# now back to path/to/repo
cd ..
git init
echo "new project" > README.txt
git add README.txt
git commit -m initial
# include the submodule
git submodule add <url> subm
git commit -m "add submodule"
```

Having done this, you have not yet "absorbed" the submodule into the main repository.  The actual submodule repository, including all of its commits and other data, still lives in `path/to/repo/subm/.git/`.  You must run:

```
git submodule absorbgitdirs
```

to move the submodule repository into `path/to/repo/.git/modules/`.  (And if your `git submodule` command lacks the `absorbgitdirs` sub-command, you have a version of Git that does not support absorbing submodules.)

Now, if you have an absorbed-style submodule, and you used `git checkout` to check out a superproject commit that—like our first commit in the superproject above—doesn't actually *have* the submodule, your superproject Git could safely remove the entire `path/to/repo/subm/` tree, including the `.git` file.  The actual submodule, including any commits you made but have not yet pushed, is safely stored in the main Git repository.  But if for any reason you have a *non*-absorbed submodule, *removing* `path/to/repo/subm/` would also remove all the files within `path/to/repo/subm/.git/`, thereby removing the entire repository.

This is clearly dangerous, and Git just doesn't do it at all, even if the submodule has been absorbed.  Perhaps Git should do it for the absorbed-submodule case, but it just doesn't, at least up through current versions of Git (2.27).